# What happens if I demolish a monument that I constructed?

Tags: rimworld, rimworld-royalty

With the new royalty content enabled I have constructed several monuments.

These were either given me as part of a quest, or because my local royal had a tantrum over eating a dinner without a table, and demanded I build a monument to remember the occasion.

What happens if I deconstruct these monuments to regain the resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that when you complete the monument, it says that you should protect it for 20 days. So I guess it is okay to remove it after 20 days. If you do so before, they send a "device" (with turrets to protect it) that disables your electricity unless you destroy that "site device".

Here is the info from the game:

[image]

Comment: Note that the penalty isn't always the same, I think I've seen one device which produced toxic fallout.